# Solr's schema and how it works

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, schema, nutch

Hey so I started researching about Solr and have a couple of questions on how Solr works. I know the schema defines what is stored and indexed in the Solr application. But I'm confuse as to how Solr knows that the "content" is the content of the site or that the url is the url?

My main goal is I'm trying to extract phone numbers from websites and I want Solr to nicely spit out 1234567890.

Comment: When you say "site" and "URL" what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ansari when i mention site i mean the overall site and when i say url i mean the link only. Sorry for the confusion. What I'm trying to do is have nutch crawl sites and then push it to solr so it can index url to phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it in Solr schema.xml by declaring all the fields and its field type. You can then query Solr for any field to search.

Refer this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

Answer (score 0):

Solr will not automatically index content from a website. You need to tell it how to index your content. Solr only knows the content you tell it to know. Extracting phone numbers sounds pretty simple so writing an update script or finding one online should not be an issue. Good luck!